# Easy migration from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, oracle, migration

I have a vb.net application working well over SQL Server 2008.
My sql requests are basic and simple, like select, insert into, update...

I'm not using any SQL Server sepcific commands or instructions.

Now I want to change my database server to Oracle, running on a Linux machine.

Is it possible??? Or I must re-write all my SQL requests?

Comment: if the SQL is ANSI-92 compliant it will ***likely*** work.  But the only way to truly know will be to test it all.

Comment: There are also few difference on dates and if you are using autoincrement fields they are supported only on the newests Oracle versions (you can change it with sequences but it's a work to do).

Comment: It's unlikely you'll get away with migrating without any changes.  But if your queries really are basic, you'll probably only need minor tweaks here and there.  For instance, if you ever use square brackets `[]` around your column or table names, or if you ever prefix your table names with `.dbo`, etc... you'll need to make adjustments.

Comment: In my experience It always takes 'some' editing when I transfer Sql. I would check every  statement carefully after migrating.

Comment: if you do need to change up any of your queries, we have tools to assist with that - Oracle SQL Developer can translate your T-SQL and database 12c has a sql translation framework that can do that 'on the fly'

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather general question (perhaps "too broad" would apply).  You definitely have some gotchas, even for simple statements:

- SUBSTR() versus SUBSTRING()
- VARCHAR2() versus VARCHAR()
- INSTR() versus CHARINDEX()
- `||` versus `+` for string concatenation
- LENGTH() versus LEN()
- TRIM() versus LTRIM()/RTRIM()
- SYSDATE versus GETDATE()

and so on.

There are also significant differences in syntax, for instance:

- SQL Server allows joins in `UPDATE`, which Oracle does not.
- Oracle limits resolution of correlated queries to a scope only only layer deep.
- SQL Server has the `APPLY` keywords for certain types of joins.
- Oracle `DATE` data type has a time component, but not SQL Server

This is by no means a comprehensive list.  It is just suggestive that you will need to do some work to move between the databases.  However, that work might be mostly cosmetic.